# What does lint_package_filename_version_match mean?

Tags: application-development

In a review of a .click package of my app, a message contained the following:

```
lint_package_filename_version_match
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen very easily, but will be fixed in the software store very soon.

Basically it's a mismatch in version numbers between

1. what you specified when uploading through the web UI of the store
2. what's in the manifest file of your click app

Before you upload, make sure you bump the version in both and make sure they're the same.

Comment: The problem is, that after you get this error you can not correct it because you are not allowed to edit the version string and you are also not allowed to upload the same click-package again.